# KeyError: in scikit-learn ColumnTransformer during data transformation

Tags: pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-transform

I'm working on a data transformation process using `scikit-learn`'s `ColumnTransformer`. I have a custom transformer class called "DataTransformation" that includes several data preprocessing steps. When I try to run the transformation pipeline, I encounter a `KeyError` with the following message: `['Company', 'TypeName', 'ScreenResolution', 'Cpu', 'Ram', 'Memory', 'Gpu', 'OpSys', 'Weight'] not in index`.

I've shared the project on [GitHub link](https://github.com/pras-ops/Laptop_price_predictor). Your insights and suggestions would be invaluable in resolving this issue.
Data_ingestion.py

```
import os
import sys
from logger import logging
from exception import CustomException
import pandas as pd

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from dataclasses import dataclass


from components.data_transfornation import DataTransformation
from components.data_transfornation import DataTransformationConfig

#from src.components.model_trainer import ModelTrainerConfig
#from src.components.model_trainer import ModelTrainer
@dataclass
class DataIngestionConfig:
    train_data_path: str=os.path.join('artifacts',"train.csv")
    test_data_path: str=os.path.join('artifacts',"test.csv")
    raw_data_path: str=os.path.join('artifacts',"data.csv")

class DataIngestion:
    def __init__(self):
        self.ingestion_config=DataIngestionConfig()

    def initiate_data_ingestion(self):
        logging.info("Entered the data ingestion method or component")
        try:
            df=pd.read_csv(r'Notebook\data\laptop_data.csv')
            logging.info('Read the dataset as dataframe')

            os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(self.ingestion_config.train_data_path),exist_ok=True)

            df.to_csv(self.ingestion_config.raw_data_path,index=False,header=True)

            logging.info("Train test split initiated")
            train_set,test_set=train_test_split(df,test_size=0.15,random_state=2)

            train_set.to_csv(self.ingestion_config.train_data_path,index=False,header=True)

            test_set.to_csv(self.ingestion_config.test_data_path,index=False,header=True)

            logging.info("Inmgestion of the data iss completed")

            return(
                self.ingestion_config.train_data_path,
                self.ingestion_config.test_data_path

            )
        except Exception as e:
            raise CustomException(e,sys)
        
if __name__=="__main__":
    obj=DataIngestion()
    train_data_path, test_data_path = obj.initiate_data_ingestion()  # Separate the paths

    data_transformation = DataTransformation()
    data_transformation.initiate_data_transformation(train_data_path, test_data_path)
    #train_arr,test_arr,_=

    #modeltrainer=ModelTrainer()
    #print(modeltrainer.initiate_model_trainer(train_arr,test_arr))
```

I checked the `DataFrame` columns and ensured that they contain all the required columns mentioned in the error message.
I verified the data preprocessing steps inside the "DataTransformation" class to make sure they are correct.
I reviewed the entire code and confirmed that the necessary columns are indeed present in the `DataFrame` before applying the transformations.

Data_transformation.py

```
import sys
import os
from dataclasses import dataclass
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd

from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from exception import CustomException
from logger import logging
from utils.utils import save_object
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.preprocessing import FunctionTransformer
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder, StandardScaler

@dataclass
class DataTransformationConfig:
    preprocessor_obj_file_path: str = os.path.join('artifacts', 'preprocessor.pkl')

class DataTransformation(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        return self

    def transform(self, X):
        logging.info("DataTransformation: Starting data transformation steps...")
        X = X.copy()
        X = pd.DataFrame(X)  # Make a copy of the DataFrame to avoid modifying the original data
        logging.info(f"Column names present in the data: {X.columns.tolist()}")
        # Extract column names from the DataFrame
        existing_columns = set(X.columns)

        # Check if all the required columns are present in the DataFrame
        required_columns = [
            'Company', 'TypeName', 'Inches', 'ScreenResolution', 'Cpu', 'Ram', 'Memory',
            'Gpu', 'OpSys', 'Weight', 'Price'
        ]
        missing_columns = set(required_columns) - existing_columns
        if missing_columns:
            logging.warning(f"Missing columns in the DataFrame: {missing_columns}")

        # Selecting and reordering columns directly
        X = X[required_columns]

        # Apply other transformations only if certain columns are present
        if 'Unnamed: 0' in X.columns:
            X.drop(columns=['Unnamed: 0'], inplace=True)
            logging.info("remove_unnamed_column")

        if 'ScreenResolution' in X.columns:
            if 'ScreenResolution' in X.columns:
                X.rename(columns={'ScreenResolution': 'Resolution'}, inplace=True)
            X.rename(columns={
                'Company': 'Brand',
                'TypeName': 'Type',
                'Inches': 'ScreenSize',
                'Ram': 'RAM',
                'Memory': 'Storage',
                'Gpu': 'GPU',
                'OpSys': 'OperatingSystem',
                'Weight': 'Weight',
                'Price_euros': 'Price'
            }, inplace=True)
            logging.info("rename_columns")

        if 'RAM' in X.columns:
            X['RAM'] = X['RAM'].str.replace('GB', '')
            X['RAM'] = X['RAM'].astype('int32')
            logging.info("remove_units and convert_ram_to_int")

        if 'Weight_kg' in X.columns:
            X['Weight_kg'] = X['Weight_kg'].str.replace('kg', '')
            X['Weight_kg'] = X['Weight_kg'].astype('float32')
            logging.info("convert_weight_to_float")

        if 'Resolution' in X.columns:
            X['TouchScreen'] = X['Resolution'].apply(lambda element: 1 if 'Touchscreen' in element else 0)
            X['IPS'] = X['Resolution'].apply(lambda element: 1 if 'IPS' in element else 0)
            logging.info("extract_touchscreen_feature and extract_ips_feature")

        if 'CPU' in X.columns:
            print("Columns before extracting CPU feature:", X.columns)
            X['Processor'] = X['CPU'].apply(lambda text: " ".join(text.split()[:3]))
            print("Columns after extracting CPU feature:", X.columns)
            logging.info("extract_cpu_feature")

        if 'Resolution' in X.columns:
            split_df = X['Resolution'].str.split('x', n=1, expand=True)
            X['X_res'] = split_df[0].str.replace(',', '').str.findall(r'(\d+\.?\d+)').apply(lambda x: x[0]).astype('int')
            X['Y_res'] = split_df[1].astype('int')
            X['PPI'] = (((X['X_res'] ** 2 + X['Y_res'] ** 2) ** 0.5) / X['ScreenSize']).astype('float')
            # Drop only the columns that are no longer needed for further processing
            X.drop(columns=['X_res', 'Y_res'], inplace=True)
            logging.info("extract_resolution_features")

        if 'CPU_name' in X.columns:
            listtoapply = ['HDD', 'SSD', 'Hybrid', 'FlashStorage']
            for value in listtoapply:
                X['Layer1'+value] = X['first'].apply(lambda x: 1 if value in x else 0)

            X['first'] = X['first'].str.replace(r'\D','')
            X['first'] = X['first'].astype('int')

            listtoapply1 = ['HDD', 'SSD', 'Hybrid', 'FlashStorage']
            X['Second'] = X['Second'].fillna("0")
            for value in listtoapply1:
                X['Layer2'+value] = X['Second'].apply(lambda x: 1 if value in x else 0)

            X['Second'] = X['Second'].str.replace(r'\D','')
            X['Second'] = X['Second'].astype('int')

            # Multiplying the elements and storing the result in subsequent columns
            X["HDD"] = (X["first"] * X["Layer1HDD"] + X["Second"] * X["Layer2HDD"])
            X["SSD"] = (X["first"] * X["Layer1SSD"] + X["Second"] * X["Layer2SSD"])

            # ... (add similar lines for Hybrid and Flash_Storage if needed)

            # Dropping unnecessary columns
            X.drop(columns=['first', 'Second', 'Layer1HDD', 'Layer1SSD', 'Layer1Hybrid',
                            'Layer1FlashStorage', 'Layer2HDD', 'Layer2SSD', 'Layer2Hybrid',
                            'Layer2FlashStorage'], inplace=True)
            X.drop(columns=['Memory'], inplace=True)
            X.drop(columns=['Hybrid', 'Flash_Storage'], inplace=True)

            # ... (add any additional processing steps if needed)

            # Processing GPU column
            X['Gpu brand'] = X['Gpu'].apply(lambda x: x.split()[0])
            X.drop(columns=['Gpu'], inplace=True)

            # Setting OpSys category
            X['OpSys'] = X['OpSys'].apply(lambda x: self.setcategory(x))

        return X

    def data_transformation_pipeline(self, data):
        # Automatically identify numerical and categorical columns
        numerical_columns = data.select_dtypes(include=['int32', 'int64', 'float32', 'float64']).columns
        categorical_columns = data.select_dtypes(include=['object']).columns

        data_transformer = DataTransformation()

        # Create a pipeline to encapsulate the data transformation steps
        data_pipeline = Pipeline(steps=[
            ('data_transform', data_transformer),
            ('scaler', StandardScaler()),
            ('one_hot_encoder', OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore'))
        ])

        # Create the ColumnTransformer
        preprocessor = ColumnTransformer(transformers=[
            ('num', data_pipeline, numerical_columns),
            ('cat', OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore'), categorical_columns)
        ])

        logging.info("data_transformation_pipeline: Starting data transformation pipeline...")

        try:
            processed_data = preprocessor.fit_transform(data)
        except KeyError as e:
            logging.error(f"data_transformation_pipeline: KeyError - {e}")
            raise  # Re-raise the exception to see the full traceback

        logging.info("data_transformation_pipeline: Data transformation pipeline completed.")

        return processed_data

    def initiate_data_transformation(self, train_path, test_path):
        try:
            train_df = pd.read_csv(train_path)
            test_df = pd.read_csv(test_path)

            logging.info("Read train and test data completed")

            logging.info("Obtaining preprocessing object")

            preprocessing_obj = self.data_transformation_pipeline(train_df)

            target_column_name = "Price"

            input_feature_train_df = train_df.drop(columns=[target_column_name], axis=1)
            target_feature_train_df = train_df[target_column_name]

            input_feature_test_df = test_df.drop(columns=[target_column_name], axis=1)
            target_feature_test_df = test_df[target_column_name]

            logging.info(
                f"Applying preprocessing object on training dataframe and testing dataframe."
            )

            # Use the fitted preprocessing object to transform both train and test data
            input_feature_train_arr = preprocessing_obj.transform(input_feature_train_df)
            input_feature_test_arr = preprocessing_obj.transform(input_feature_test_df)

            train_arr = np.c_[input_feature_train_arr, np.array(target_feature_train_df)]
            test_arr = np.c_[input_feature_test_arr, np.array(target_feature_test_df)]

            logging.info(f"Saved preprocessing object.")

            save_object(
                file_path=self.data_transformation_config.preprocessor_obj_file_path,
                obj=preprocessing_obj
            )

            # Log the columns in the DataFrame after transformation
            logging.info("Columns in the transformed train DataFrame:")
            logging.info(pd.DataFrame(input_feature_train_arr, columns=input_feature_train_df.columns))

            logging.info("Columns in the transformed test DataFrame:")
            logging.info(pd.DataFrame(input_feature_test_arr, columns=input_feature_test_df.columns))

            return (
                train_arr,
                test_arr,
                self.data_transformation_config.preprocessor_obj_file_path,
            )
        except Exception as e:
            raise CustomException(e, sys)
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\pj\desktop\end to end project\laptop_price_predictor\src\components\data_transfornation.py", line 179, in initiate_data_transformation
    preprocessing_obj = self.data_transformation_pipeline(train_df)
  File "c:\users\pj\desktop\end to end project\laptop_price_predictor\src\components\data_transfornation.py", line 161, in data_transformation_pipeline
    processed_data = preprocessor.fit_transform(data)
  File "C:\Users\pj\anaconda3\envs\Lpp\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\_set_output.py", line 140, in wrapped
    data_to_wrap = f(self, X, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\pj\anaconda3\envs\Lpp\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py", line 1151, in wrapper
    return fit_method(estimator, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\pj\anaconda3\envs\Lpp\lib\site-packages\sklearn\compose\_column_transformer.py", line 743, in fit_transform
    result = self._fit_transform(X, y, _fit_transform_one)
  File "C:\Users\pj\anaconda3\envs\Lpp\lib\site-packages\sklearn\compose\_column_transformer.py", line 670, in _fit_transform
    return Parallel(n_jobs=self.n_jobs)(
  File "C:\Users\pj\anaconda3\envs\Lpp\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\parallel.py", line 65, in __call__
    return super().__call__(iterable_with_config)
  File "C:\Users\pj\anaconda3\envs\Lpp\lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py", line 1855, in __call__
    return output if self.return_generator else list(output)
  File "C:\Users\pj\anaconda3\envs\Lpp\lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py", line 1784, in _get_sequential_output
    res = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\pj\anaconda3\envs\Lpp\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\parallel.py", line 127, in __call__
    return self.function(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\pj\anaconda3\envs\Lpp\lib\site-packages\sklearn\pipeline.py", line 950, in _fit_transform_one
    res = transformer.fit_transform(X, y, **fit_params)
  File "C:\Users\pj\anaconda3\envs\Lpp\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py", line 1151, in wrapper
    return fit_method(estimator, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\pj\anaconda3\envs\Lpp\lib\site-packages\sklearn\pipeline.py", line 464, in fit_transform
    Xt = self._fit(X, y, **fit_params_steps)
  File "C:\Users\pj\anaconda3\envs\Lpp\lib\site-packages\sklearn\pipeline.py", line 370, in _fit
    X, fitted_transformer = fit_transform_one_cached(
  File "C:\Users\pj\anaconda3\envs\Lpp\lib\site-packages\joblib\memory.py", line 353, in __call__
    return self.func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\pj\anaconda3\envs\Lpp\lib\site-packages\sklearn\pipeline.py", line 950, in _fit_transform_one
    res = transformer.fit_transform(X, y, **fit_params)
  File "C:\Users\pj\anaconda3\envs\Lpp\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\_set_output.py", line 140, in wrapped
    data_to_wrap = f(self, X, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\pj\anaconda3\envs\Lpp\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py", line 915, in fit_transform
    return self.fit(X, **fit_params).transform(X)
  File "C:\Users\pj\anaconda3\envs\Lpp\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\_set_output.py", line 140, in wrapped
    data_to_wrap = f(self, X, *args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\pj\desktop\end to end project\laptop_price_predictor\src\components\data_transfornation.py", line 45, in transform
    X = X[required_columns]
  File "C:\Users\pj\anaconda3\envs\Lpp\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3767, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns._get_indexer_strict(key, "columns")[1]
  File "C:\Users\pj\anaconda3\envs\Lpp\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 5877, in _get_indexer_strict
    self._raise_if_missing(keyarr, indexer, axis_name)
  File "C:\Users\pj\anaconda3\envs\Lpp\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 5941, in _raise_if_missing
    raise KeyError(f"{not_found} not in index")
KeyError: "['Company', 'TypeName', 'ScreenResolution', 'Cpu', 'Ram', 'Memory', 'Gpu', 'OpSys', 'Weight'] not in index"

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "src/components/data_ingestion.py", line 58, in <module>
    data_transformation.initiate_data_transformation(train_data_path, test_data_path)
  File "c:\users\pj\desktop\end to end project\laptop_price_predictor\src\components\data_transfornation.py", line 220, in initiate_data_transformation
    raise CustomException(e, sys)
exception.CustomException: Error occured in python script name [c:\users\pj\desktop\end to end project\laptop_price_predictor\src\components\data_transfornation.py] line number [179] error message["['Company', 'TypeName', 'ScreenResolution', 'Cpu', 'Ram', 'Memory', 'Gpu', 'OpSys', 'Weight'] not in index"]
```

Comment: You should strive to make a [mre]; there's a lot going on here that doesn't seem directly relevant to the error. And without (a version of) the data, we can't replicate the problem to test. // I think the problem may be that you use a column transformer to slice down to numeric columns, but then expect some categorical ones.

Comment: Thank you for your response and understanding. I acknowledge the importance of providing a minimal reproducible example,and iapologizefor the complexityofthe code shared earlier. Regarding the issue, I have carefully reviewed the feedback and considered the advice to strive for a minimal reproducible example.I encountered a specific problem in this part of the code. In the DataTransformation class, the transform method, Df X is being copied to avoid modifying the original data during transformations. it appears that the DF is not being copied correctly, which is unexpected dropping of columns.

Comment: Try adding a `print` statement just before the line `X = X[required_columns]` to see exactly what columns are in `X`.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! I followed your advice and added a print statement just before the line X = X[required_columns]. It seems the issue was that the DataFrame X had only 3 rows instead of the expected 12. I'm currently investigating the root cause. If you'd like to take a look, here's the link to my project on GitHub: [link](https://github.com/pras-ops/Laptop_price_predictor). Any further insights would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I'm reasonably certain the issue is what I mentioned earlier: you're using the custom transformation in a `ColumnTransformer` that gets applied just to numeric (int and float) column types, but you're expecting a bunch of string columns. Those don't show up, because the column transformer got rid of them.

Comment: Thank you for your response and insight into the issue. I appreciate your help. After reviewing your comments, I agree that the problem is related to custom transformation being applied only to numeric columns in the ColumnTransformer, while I also expect to see string columns. I made the necessary corrections, but the error persists. The updated code is available in my[GitHub repository] (https://github.com/pras-ops/Laptop_price_predictor). Please have another look and advise on how to resolve this.